# Why is this integral always non-negative?

Tags: calculus

I don't understand why the following integral is always non-negative.

$$ 
\int_{0}^{1}(f'(x))^2dx $$

Where $f(x)$ can be any real valued function on $x$ and $$f(0)=f(1)=0$$.

Comment: If you think of the integral as a limit of Riemann sums (it's not clear to me that you do, or that this would even work for all differentiable functions $f$), it's pretty clear. Each Riemann sum (irrespective of partition or choices of points) will be a sum of nonnegative numbers (because squares of real numbers are nonnegative) and hence nonnegative. Any limit of nonnegative numbers (in particular, the integral in question) is also nonnegative. So whenever that integral makes sense, it's nonnegative. The hypotheses on $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ are not needed for this conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f'(x)$ is a real-valued function, $(f'(x))^2$ is always positive. The area under a positve graph cannot be negative. Here a visualization:
[image]

Comment: Fond of  visualization inside proofs.